# I am getting 400 Error when I run my application.py file

Tags: python, flask

I am creating a python application with the application below:

```
from flask import Flask, jsonify, request
from flask_cors import CORS
import pandas as pd

item_similarity_df = pd.read_csv("movie_similarity.csv", index_col=0)

app = Flask(__name__)
CORS(app)

@app.route("/")
def hello_from_root():
    return jsonify(message='Hello from root!')

@app.route("/recms", methods = ["POST"])
def make_rec():
  if request.method == "POST":
        data = request.json
        movie = data["title"]
        #curl -X POST http://0.0.0.0:80/recms -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d '{"movie_title":"Heat (1995)"}'
        try: 
            similar_score = item_similarity_df[movie]
            similar_movies = similar_score.sort_values(ascending=False)[1:50]
            api_recommendations = similar_movies.index.to_list()
        except:
            api_recommendations = ['Movie not found']
        return {"rec_movie":api_recommendations}


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=80)
```

I save this file as application.py.

After that, I start my application.py and I got the output below from the Terminal:

```
* Serving Flask app 'application'
 * Debug mode: off
WARNING: This is a development server. Do not use it in a production deployment. Use a production WSGI server instead.
 * Running on all addresses (0.0.0.0)
 * Running on http://127.0.0.1:80
 * Running on http://192.168.1.106:80
```

Then, when I run curl -X POST http://192.168.1.106:80/recms -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d '{"movie_title":"Heat (1995)"}'

I got this error:

192.168.1.106 - - [10/Aug/2022 00:19:16] "POST /recms HTTP/1.1" 400 -

May I know what is the root cause and how can I fix this issue?

You can get the movie_similarity.csv from the link attached.

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1JRgRD8KI-L33YXZArSoFDp4Sn4G963no/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 1):

I think there is an issue in the code with regards to `movie_title`, which is referenced in the code as `title`.
That probably creates an exception.

I really recommend creating a local debugging environment where you can create a breakpoint and go through the lines of code looking for where the exception happens. I recommend Pycharm community :)

Comment: I agree. That's the problem. The view function could not be executed, hence Flask returned 400 error because client's POST data was not correct.

Comment: Hi, even though I change the movie_title to the title or vice versa but still not working. Do you have any idea how to fix this error?